# return an Observable after Subject.next call

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, rxjs

I'm working on an Ionic 2 project and there are two important features to logout user and clear the db remotely. This is the code I'm working on

```
private logoutEvent: Subject<any> = new Subject();
private clearDbEvent: Subject<any> = new Subject();


this.logoutEvent.take(1).subscribe(() => {
 // do something before logout
 // has a loader and dismiss the loader after 3 seconds in this block
});

this.clearDbEvent.take(1)
  .skipUntil(this.logoutEvent.take(1))
  .concat(this.resetDb())
  .subscibe()

private resetDb() {
 return Observable.forkJoin(
        Observable.fromPromise(this.getLocaldb.destroy()),
        Observable.fromPromise(this.getStarogeDb.destroy())
     );
}
```

user can logged out invoking the 
**logoutEvent.next()** call ( I'm using pouchdb syncing feature to do this) and it's working properly. What I want to do is, before **clearDbEvent** call, need to invoke **logoutEvent** event. I'am using Rxjs to do this.

what is the best way to invoke the clearDbEvent after complete the logout event ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the function switchMap could help you?

Here you can see a tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6lKoLwGlglE&t=18s

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to trigger `clearDbEvent` after `logoutEvent` completes you'll need to add it to the `complete` handler in `subscribe`.

```
this.logoutEvent.take(1).subscribe(() => {
  ...
}, undefined, () => this.clearDbEvent.next());
```

Eventually, you could use the `finally` operator that is going to be called after the `logoutEvent` completes and unsubscribes.

```
this.logoutEvent
    .take(1)
    .finally(() => this.clearDbEvent.next())
    .subscribe(() => {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: don't need to clear the db when logout. What I'm expecting logout the user before clear the db.

Comment: Then use `this.clearDbEvent.do(() => this.logoutEvent.next())...`

Comment: @martin Did you ever find a solid solution for this? I'm working through this puzzle now. I feel like I'm close, but I was hoping for a confirmation somewhere and your SO question is the best I can find so far.